# Alternative Partition Handler Implementations

Tags: spring-batch

I am looking at the Spring batch documentation (2.2.7) and it discusses the PartitionHandler.

The PartitionHandler interface can have specialized implementations for a variety of fabric types: e.g. simple RMI remoting, EJB remoting, custom web service, JMS, Java Spaces, shared memory grids (like Terracotta or Coherence), grid execution fabrics (like GridGain). Spring Batch does not contain implementations for any proprietary grid or remoting fabrics.

Does anyone have any other implementations?

Comment: Why do you need other implementation ? What are  you gonna do with them ?

Comment: We are trying to use JBoss Messaging and are getting failures where messages are being lost.....So looking for another option for the partitioning

Comment: JMS Configuration should prevent the message loss.  This doesn't sound like an issue with using the wrong partition handler...it sounds like an issue with how you're using the `MessageChannelPartitionHandler`.